# Use a python library in a scala project

Tags: python, scala, shared-libraries

I am new to scala. I am working on a **scala** project which requires me to use a specific algorithm, which its library is available in **python**, I want to know if is there any way to use the library in my project.

Comment: Have a look https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/362926 though I wouldn't really recommend it. Are you sure there's no Scala or Java implementation or the Python thing?

Comment: I agree that a Scala or Java version would be better, if you can find it. If you must go down the Python route see if the library is compatible with Jython.

Comment: Take a look to [**scalapy**](https://github.com/shadaj/scalapy)